# How to use spatie/laravel-permission package with react js for roles?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I want to develop a system module based using Laravel 6 and reactjs 16. It will be included Roles and Permissions functionalities.
I am using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission for roles permissions. I just want to know how to use it with reactJs. 
Laravel 6.0 is being used for database and backend functionalities.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -3):

IMHO it's not depending from front-end technologies (like react).
And suggest you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@boolfalse/laravel-multi-auth-using-different-tables-part-3-admin-permissions-f78c9abc7a5b) or watch appropriate [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCfPmVgXQBc&list=PL8gDJhl8MloV0_q1nQ0LViK-u3jiVQBZL&index=4).

By the way, I don't think that here we need to write about installation steps for that popular package. Because all that stuff written in the official package Readme, and issues are there too. So if you will get an error, or have some troubles, people will try to help for the specific case

Comment: Thanks for answer but you have given me the solution that is not suitable for react js. It will be good if I will develop a JS frameworks' independent platforms. Have you any solution for reactjs specially.

Comment: Anyway I don't see the question about some error or problem or something like that. So therefore there will not any exact answer I think. But I will follow to the answers of this question and will happy to see the answers of those who downvoted my answer. I'm not agree about that and want to see the right answer of this if it's exists, so I will improve my knowledge. Thanks